# how to view contents of a imported jdk class file in intellij

Tags: java, intellij-idea, java-8, java-7

Newbie java programmer here. Is there any way I can view the contents of a class file in the Intelli J idea? Suppose I import a class java.lang.Math.* is there any way I can view the contents of *?

Comment: double click the class file ? for a class that you don't know where is its class file just right click on the class name and click `Go To Declaration`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a class file you have, you can just open it in intellij by double-clicking(you may need to import the file if it isn't part of your project).

For a class you're using and you don't know where is its class file, like `Math` here :

```
int x=Math.min(2,3);
```

Just right click on `Math` word, `Go To` and then `Declaration` as shown here : 
[image]

Alternatively you can follow @Faisal's suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Have your cursor on the class name and hit `F4`. It will direct you to the declaration of that resource.

Comment: I tried your method dude but it didn't work, just thought of checking the keymap in the ide settings and f4 isn't mapped anywhere. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @RaynerDaCruz it did work for me, key bindings in general depends on IDE version and settings